# Can't change fonts in ggplot/geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't set my fonts in geom_text. Here is what I tried:

```
    labels_test<-data.frame(a=c("a","b","c"),b=c(1:3),c=c(3:1))
    # works
    ggplot () + geom_text(data=labels_test,aes(b,c,label=a),color="blue")
    # does not work: 
    ggplot () + geom_text(data=labels_test,aes(b,c,label=a),color="blue",family="Times")
    # error message:  In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,:
    # Font family not found in Windows font database
```

I already imported all fonts as indicated [here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html). Any ideas what is still going wrong?

Comment: does it work if you try `windowsFonts(Times=windowsFont("TT Times New Roman"))` first?

Comment: yes it does. thank you. you should post it as an answer. Can you explain it? And do I have to do this in all scripts when I want to use diffrent fonts?

Comment: I'm on mac just now so I can't really fiddle around but [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/781cT5yMqCg) might help but mainly the idea of  this is once you have installed the fonts you give them to R to use explicitly

Comment: You can bulk import your fonts with package {extrafont} as explained in this article: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would try"

```
windowsFonts(Times=windowsFont("TT Times New Roman"))
```

In doing this your specifying explicitly the  Windows Font mapping.

Comment: So how would you go for doing it for every single imported font?

Answer (score 41):

The other answers didn't solve my problem (Windows 10).

The key for my system was to call `extrafont::loadfonts(device="win")` ***prior to*** `library(ggplot2)`.

```
extrafont::loadfonts(device="win")
#extrafont::fonttable()
#extrafont::font_import("C:/Windows/Fonts/", pattern = "RobotoCondensed")
library(ggplot2)
```

**Common problem with font locations:**

I had installed the fonts from a random folder with `extrafont::font_import()` previously. As such `extrafont::fonttable()` referenced the files in my `C:\Windows\Fonts\` folder.  To fix this I reset my `extrafonts::fonttable()` with `install.packages("extrafontdb")` in order to clear a reference to the fonts in a different location.

**Edit regarding saving:**

Deeper down the rabbit hole.  Saving was an additional challenge.  In order to `extrafont::loadfonts(device="pdf")` I had to make sure no fonts in my `extrafont::fonttable()` had identical family names and bold/italic status. I edited `extrafont:::fonttable_file()` to resolve any duplicate bold/italic fonts within my family.  Using Roboto Condensed I renamed the light fonts' font family to "Roboto Condensed Light".

Saving with `ggsave(device="pdf")` then worked. Opening the files in acrobat the fonts did not display correctly. I tried embedding the fonts with ghostscript as well as using the cairo_pdf device.  The easiest and most functional solution was to open the .pdf files in Illustrator (the fonts display fine there) and immediately re-save them again as .pdf.

**Edit 2 regarding saving:**

Saving as .eps was the only way to preserve the file in both illustrator and acrobat.  The result is perfect. `ggsave(g, file="Figure.eps", fonts=c("FONT FAMILIES USED", "Roboto Condensed", "Roboto Condensed Light"))`

**Final plotting code:**

Here is my final set of calls I use before plotting. Comments are setup commands that need to be run once only.

```
# Plotting
extrafont::loadfonts(device="pdf")
extrafont::loadfonts(device="postscript")
# extrafont::font_import("C:/Windows/Fonts/", pattern = "RobotoCondensed", prompt = F)
# extrafont::fonttable()
# C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library/extrafontdb/fontmap/ - Change lights to "Roboto Condensed Light"
# After ggsave(device="pdf") or ggsave(device="eps") open and resave the file in Illustrator
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)
```

Comment: It may seem obvious, but it's worth adding: you'll want to make sure you have fonts loaded by executing `extrafont::font_import()` before attempting to load any fonts.

Answer (score 20):

You must import the system fonts using the command:

```
font_import(paths = NULL, recursive = TRUE, prompt = TRUE,pattern = NULL)
```

Comment: This is actually the real _answer_ to the question.

Comment: If you have a lot of fonts, this solution will take a long time.  Use `pattern="Times"` or something to reduce the number of fonts loaded

Comment: Is this a one time operation or something you must run every time? Looks like it might be one time to me

Answer (score 3):

I tried the different solutions here but none worked for me (win10, R 3.4.3). 
This is what worked for me:

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win")
```

It did not matter if I did it before or after `library(ggplot2)`

Sources:

1. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/extrafont.pdf
2. [Changing fonts in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522732/changing-fonts-in-ggplot2)