# Is it possible to set geom_text size via theme?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change a base font for all `geom_text` elements.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3), label = c("a", "b", "c")
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + geom_text()
```

[image: base size]

I tried setting `theme` text, but it doesn't seem to effect `geom_text` elements.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + 
  geom_text() + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 42))
```

[image: size = 42]

I've seen some older posts suggesting using `base_size` but it looks like it is no longer supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change fonts in ggplot/geom\_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733732/cant-change-fonts-in-ggplot-geom-text)

Comment: I don't think this is possible, for a good reason (but perhaps I will stand corrected): The difference being that  (1) the font size of theme elements is fixed and can be changed globally through e.g. `theme` or `theme_set(theme_grey(base_size = 42))` (this is still supported), and (2) the `size` in `geom_text` is a `geom_*` aesthetic and can be dynamically mapped to variables. While you can fix `size` in `geom_text`, you can see how the mapping is different by setting `size = 42` inside `geom_text` giving a different (larger) font size than `size = 42` inside `element_text`.

Comment: For those who come later, this _is_ a hack, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76222642/3358272 (override the `.pt` value stored in the `ggplot2` namespace).

Comment: I do not agreee that being unable to set the size of `geom_text` through `theme` is for a good reason. Yes, the size can be mapped to variables, but mapping a variable to size should change only the size relative to some baseline. That baseline should be set through `theme`.

Answer (score -2):

You can control the size by using it inside the `geom_text()` function.

```
library(ggplot2)


df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3), label = c("a", "b", "c")
)

# use 'size' in geom_text function
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + 
  geom_text(size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes, you don't have access to geom_text. For instance, using package factoextra. Is there a solution then?