# theme with base_size and geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358461/is-it-possible-to-set-geom-text-size-via-theme) which had a "not possible" answer at that time, but hopefully things change

I set font family and font size via theme

```
theme_set(theme_minimal(
  base_family="Calibri",
  base_size=8
))
```

but then I use `ggplot` with `geom_text`, `geom_text` has a life of its own and does not seem to take the font size (at least) from the theme

```
theme_set(theme_minimal(
  base_size=8
))


df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3), label = c("a", "b", "c")
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + geom_text()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default font size for `geom_text()` using `update_geom_defaults()`.

```
library(ggplot2) 

theme_set(theme_minimal(
  base_size=8
)) 

update_geom_defaults("text", list(size = 8 / .pt))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = label)) + geom_text()
```

[image]

Note use of the [`.pt` conversion factor](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#font-size) to set the size as 8 points rather that 8 mm.