# ggplot2 geom_text font size on linux

Tags: r, linux, windows, ggplot2

I recently switched a workstation from windows to linux, and for interactive use, the font sizes as chosen by `geom_text` are dramatically different. I'm trying to find a way to set the base size for `geom_text` so that the use of `geom_text(aes(size=..))` can be used interchangeably between windows and linux with similar-enough results.

Notably, without changing the actual code that produces the plot.

Code:

```r
R.version[c("system","version.string")]
#                _                                
# system         x86_64, mingw32                  
# version.string R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)

plot(mpg ~ disp, mtcars, type="n")
with(mtcars, text(disp, mpg, cyl))

library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
# [1] ‘3.4.2’
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, label = cyl)) + geom_text()
```

[image: windows base graphics]

[image: windows ggplot2]

The font size for base `text` and ggplot2 `geom_text` are approximately the same.

Same code on Ubuntu 22.04:

```r
R.version[c("system","version.string")]
#                _                           
# system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
# version.string R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)

plot(mpg ~ disp, mtcars, type="n")
with(mtcars, text(disp, mpg, cyl))

library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")
# [1] ‘3.4.2’
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, label = cyl)) + geom_text()
```

[image: linux base graphics]

[image: linux ggplot2]

The text sizes are markedly different.

Since there is much legacy code that needs to run similarly (I recognize *some* differences will sneak through), I would like to be able to set something (perhaps in `.Rprofile`) that will render similar font sizes for both `geom_text` and axis labels and titles, etc.

- Something like `theme_set(theme_gray(base_size=20))` does not affect `geom_text` sizes.
- This is not a symptom of "high DPI monitor", this has been tested on both high and low DPI displays (on the same linux system).
- Running `extrafont::loadfonts()` (with fully-imported fonts) before loading ggplot2 does not fix it.

[Is it possible to set geom_text size via theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358461/is-it-possible-to-set-geom-text-size-via-theme)
is very very similar: to be clear, if there is a way to set it to a known/common size basis, *regardless* of the ability to set it to arbitrary values, I'm good with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. The easiest solution I can think of is a bit hacky, but effective, requiring only a single line of code to be added to a script after `ggplot2` is loaded. It is to overwrite `ggplot::.pt`, which is the multiplier used to convert the `size` parameter in ggplot layers to font sizes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

.pt
#> [1] 2.845276

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, label = cyl)) +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

If we overwrite `.pt` like this:

```r
assignInNamespace(".pt", 5, ns = "ggplot2")
```

Then we can see the font size increases appropriately.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, label = cyl)) +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

Notice that the theme elements are left alone since these do not use `.pt`.

You will need to tinker with the value to get the appropriate multiplier that makes your two systems match.

<sup>Created on 2023-05-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hacky and just what I needed. Thanks!