# How do I change the font for geom_text in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to set the font for `geom_text` to Roboto condensed.

I tried to do it wih hrbrbr themes, but it doesn't appear to be in roboto condensed.

I know this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733732/cant-change-fonts-in-ggplot-geom-text) has an answer, but it requires changing the font system wide.

Can I apply roboto condensed to a ggplot chart for only the geom_text labels?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the answer you have linked *does* change the font system-wide. It just gives you the ability to access a font. I'll demonstrate here using a handwriting font to make this very obvious:

```r
windowsFonts(Script = windowsFont("Edwardian Script ITC"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = rownames(mtcars)), family = "Script")
```

You can see the axis labels and markers are not affected.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>