# Specify default font for entire ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to specify a font for all text when making a ggplot.  I found I can set the base size under ggplot's selected theme but cannot find a clear example of setting to a monospaced font such as say Courier or preferably Roboto Mono for the entire plot.

This solution looked like it should work:

[Can't change fonts in ggplot/geom_text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733732/cant-change-fonts-in-ggplot-geom-text)

But no joy in my attempt below

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device = "win")

require(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, group = carb)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_light(base_size = 15, base_family = "Roboto Mono")
```

Comment: Have you registered your fonts? If you type ```windowsFonts()$`Roboto Mono` ``` do you get `NULL` or `Roboto Mono` returned in the console?

Comment: Yes I get NULL - will look into registering fonts ... OK just noticed how to below ... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going along with @Allan Cameron 's response.

```
windowsFonts('Roboto Mono'=windowsFont("Roboto Mono"))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, group = carb)) +
  geom_point()  +
  theme_light(base_size = 15, base_family = windowsFonts()$`Roboto Mono`)
```